# Add different items in listview for each tab among 3 tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs

I have created 3 tabs in the activity. Now I want to add a `ListView` for every tab. But the contents of the tabs should be different. How to achieve this?

Comment: all 3 tabs contain a listview? is the structure of listview same for all three tabs?

Comment: You might need to use three different fragments for this as you said that you have different layout structures for the listviews.

Answer (score 1):

you can have three different `layout files` and three different kind of `adapters`, and based on the tab selected, `inflate the relevant layout` file and `set values in the particular adapter` and set adapter to listview.

OR

you can use fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You can have just one `ListFragment`, and put a switch case in it and for each tab, set different `Adapter`.

But for better performance it is better to have 3 different `Fragments` with same xml. But different Adapters.

Hope it's helpful and for more details please feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for yur answers. problem has been solved. I set the content of 3 different xml with its respective java class for each tab :)